# Box2D (Processing): how to solve the 'Could not invoke the "beginContact()" method for some reason' error?

Tags: java, exception, processing, collision-detection, box2d

First of all, check this out ([link](https://github.com/shiffman/Box2D-for-Processing/tree/master/Box2D-for-Processing/dist/box2d_processing/examples/CollisionsAndControl)): it's an example program taken from the Processing Box2D library on github, which displays a box at the center of the screen (it can be moved around with the mouse) while a cascade of little balls fall on it; whenever a ball hits the box, that ball turns red. I copypasted the four .pde files into a single .pde sketch, run it, and it works ***perfectly.***

Now, onto my problem. I'm currently making a game in Processing: you have a ball, a player 1 and a player 2 (both of which can be moved around using the keyboard). Box2D is in charge of the physical interactions between each player and the ball, and I must say it handles them pretty well. Each of the three main objects has its own class. Now, I want stuff to happen as soon as player 1 makes contact with the ball. And that example code seems perfect for this scope, right? It works on my computer, after all.

So, I started copying the relevant parts:

- I copypasted all the 'import's at the beginning of my code;
- I added *box2d.listenForCollisions();* inside setup();

I also added these two functions at the very bottom of my sketch:

```
void beginContact(Contact cp) {
  Fixture f1 = cp.getFixtureA();
  Fixture f2 = cp.getFixtureB();
  Body b1 = f1.getBody();
  Body b2 = f2.getBody();
  Object o1 = b1.getUserData();
  Object o2 = b2.getUserData();

  if (o1.getClass() == Box.class) {
    Particle p = (Particle) o2;
    p.change();
  } 
  else if (o2.getClass() == Box.class) {
    Particle p = (Particle) o1;
    p.change();
  }
}

void endContact(Contact cp) {
}
```

Which I promptly changed into this (I basically renamed the classes, and substituted p.change(), the method that turned the balls red in that sketch, with what I want to happen when contact is being made):

```
(... same ...)

  if (o1.getClass() == Player.class) {
    Ball p = (Ball) o2;
    //do stuff when contact happens
  } 
  else if (o2.getClass() == Player.class) {
    Ball p = (Ball) o1;
    //do stuff when contact happens
  }
}

void endContact(Contact cp) {
}
```

But guess what? I get a **'Could not invoke the "beginContact()" method for some reason'** error! I don't think I'm lacking any crucial files or libraries, since that example worked fine in my computer and all I did was just copypaste and run the code.

I cannot paste here my whole code because it's huge, but I swear the Player class (player 1 class), the Enemy class (player 2 class) and the Ball class all have their fixtures, and there's literally nothing in my classes that differs in a substantial way from those from the example sketch. The bodies are all of dynamic type, the players are rectangular boxes like the box in the example, and the ball is a pure circle like the little balls that turned red there.

What is happening? Did I miss an important line from that code? Even though the example code runs perfectly without needing any additional files, I should mention that the console also prints an *'at shiffman.box2d.Box2DContactListener.beginContact(Box2DContactListener.java:54)'* error: now, like I said, I don't need that Box2DContactListener.java file in my computer to run the example sketch... but anyway, if I read it up online ([link](https://github.com/shiffman/Box2D-for-Processing/blob/master/Box2D-for-Processing/src/shiffman/box2d/Box2DContactListener.java)), I can see this is what it's referring to:

```
public void beginContact(Contact c) {
    if (beginMethod != null) {
        try {
            beginMethod.invoke(parent, new Object[] { c });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not invoke the \"beginContact()\" method for some reason.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            beginMethod = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? This should **not** be your full project, but it should be a simple example program that shows us what's going on in as few lines as possible. Also, please post the full stack trace, not just the error message you're printing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, before the if statement, you have to check if either of the objects is 'null'.
In case it is, you just have to break.
You can just simply paste this:

`if (o1==null || o2==null)
     return;`